# $.getScript for every element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The var `json.script` is an array. Every element is a path to a script, which I want to load via `$.getScript`.
It should look like something like this - but I don't know how to loop the array to get every array-element:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( json.script ),
    $.getScript( json.script ),
    $.getScript( json.script ),
    $.getScript( json.script ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
)
.done(function( script, textStatus ) { success(json); })
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) { errormessage( exception ); });
```

Comment: do you want to load the scripts asynchronously on one after the other, because you will need different code for these cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` to call `$.getScript` on each element of the array. Then you can apply `$.when` to the result of this:

```
$.when.apply(null, json.script.map(function(e) {
    return $.getScript(e);
}))
.done(function( script, textStatus ) { success(json); })
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) { errormessage( exception ); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over teh array and create a array of promises which can be passed to `$.when`

```
//create a array of promises, one for each item in the array
var promises = $.map(json.script, function (script) {
    return $.getScript(script)
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function (script, textStatus) {
    success(json);
}).fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    errormessage(exception);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q09gxktg/)